# VBA Code to add an adaptive formula to all cells where both the respective column and row is greater than nothing

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a spreadsheet that I am wanting a reasonably complex formula on potentially lots of cells (D43:ZZ1000) based on 2 factors (1) that column C has something in the row and (2) that Row 6 has something in the columns.  Coding this in excel using formula increases the file size from 5Mb to well over 60Mb rendering the workbook unusable.  There would only be rare occasions that the full number of rows and columns are ever used so have the ability to adapt the cell population would really help.  The basic code I've written so far is: but I'm struggling to de-bug it and only have a very basic VBA knowledge.

```
Sub Formula_CF()
'
Dim Col_Rng As Range
Col_Rng = Range("D5:ZZ5")
Dim Row_Rng As Range
Row_Rng = Range("A43:A1000")
Dim Date_Rng As Range
Date_Rng = Range("D6:ZZ6")
Dim Name_Rng As Range
Name_Rng = Range("B43:B1000")
'
Dim Start As Range
Start = Range("D43")
Dim Finish As Range
Finish = Range("ZZ1000")
'
If Date_Rng <> "" And Name_Rng <> "" Then
    Range(Start) = _
        "=IF(" & Col_Rng & "$6<>" & """" & "," & _
        "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EO:$EO,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!$C" & Row_Rng & ",Sheet1!$EN:$EN,Sheet2!" & Date_Rng & "$6)+" & _
        "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EQ:$EQ,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!$C" & Row_Rng & ",Sheet1!$EP:$EP,Sheet2!" & Date_Rng & "$6)+" & _
        "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$ES:$ES,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!$C" & Row_Rng & ",Sheet1!$ER:$ER,Sheet2!" & Date_Rng & "$6)+" & _
        "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EU:$EU,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!$C" & Row_Rng & ",Sheet1!$ET:$ET,Sheet2!" & Date_Rng & "$6),"""")"
End If
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it need to be a formula, or would just the values also work?

Comment: Hi, the values would work but it would need to be adaptive from cell C43 through to ZZ10000.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can try something like this:

```vb
Sub Formula_CF()
    
    Dim rngResults As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngRow6 As Range, rngColC As Range
    Dim row6Vals, colAVals, arrResults, r As Long, c As Long, addr1, addr2
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngResults = ws.Range("D43:ZZ1000") 'range to be populated
    arrResults = rngResults.Value
    
    Set rngRow6 = rngResults.EntireColumn.Rows(6) 'row 6 above rngResults
    row6Vals = rngRow6.Value
    
    colAVals = rngResults.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value 'Col A values left of rngResults
    Set rngColC = rngResults.EntireRow.Columns("C")    'Col C range left of rngResults
    
    'loop over the results array
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrResults, 1)
        addr1 = rngColC.Cells(r).Address   'Col C cell address
        For c = 1 To UBound(arrResults, 2)
            
            If Len(colAVals(r, 1)) > 0 And Len(row6Vals(1, c)) > 0 Then 'value in row6/columnA?
                addr2 = rngRow6.Cells(c).Address 'Row 6 cell address
                'populate the array with the evaluated result
                arrResults(r, c) = Application.Evaluate( _
                    "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EO:$EO,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!" & addr1 & ",Sheet1!$EN:$EN,Sheet2!" & addr2 & ")+" & _
                    "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EQ:$EQ,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!" & addr1 & ",Sheet1!$EP:$EP,Sheet2!" & addr2 & ")+" & _
                    "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$ES:$ES,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!" & addr1 & ",Sheet1!$ER:$ER,Sheet2!" & addr2 & ")+" & _
                    "SUMIFS(Sheet1!$EU:$EU,Sheet1!$G:$G,Sheet2!" & addr1 & ",Sheet1!$ET:$ET,Sheet2!" & addr2 & ")")
            Else
                arrResults(r, c) = Empty
            End If
            
        Next c
    Next r
    
    rngResults.Value = arrResults 'put the array values onto the sheet
    
End Sub
```